# How do I attach an object to a rotating object in Flash?

Tags: flash-cs5, tween, motion

I have a multi-layered animation, comprised of motion tweens at the moment. I would like to attach an object to another so that when it rotates, the attached object will move in an orbit based on the point where it is anchored.

Is this possible without ActionScript?

If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not dynamic, you can group the objects together and do the tween on the grouped object. You can always change the anchor point to suit where you need it. So you can also try moving the anchor point of your second object to be overlapping the first object and use the same tween parameters.

Comment: Placed them on the same layer and tweened it. Worked perfectly. Much appreciated.